# Broadcast Receiver com Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, broadcastreceiver

estou com uma necessidade e já busquei bastante, mas ainda não descobrir como fazer, tenho uma base no firebase-database do google que é atualizada de 10 em 10 minutos, quando chega uma informação nova no firebase o realtime modifica os formulários no app em milissegundos, mas quando o app esta fechado eu não sei que houve modificação.
Preciso que quando exista uma modificação no firebase o app receba esses dados que suba o notification para os usuários.
Procurei vários sites e videos e ninguém trabalho com Broadcast e firebase, mas creio que exista alguma coisa, eu tbm verifiquei a possibilidade de usar a função Services do android, mas o mesmo deve ser acionado pela aplicação e isso seria impossível já que a mesma esta fechada.

Alguém consegui me ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o [Firebase Cloud Messaging em conjunto com Cloud Functions](https://medium.com/android-dev-moz/fcf-fcm-d5828e7eab94).

Adicione o FCM ao Android como mostra o artigo e crie uma função quer irá enviar as notificações. Ela ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions'); //Constante para invocar o Firebase Cloud Functions
const admin = require('firebase-admin'); //Constante para invocar o Firebase Admin SDK
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase); //Inicializar o Firebase com configurações do functions

//Função quer detecta alterações na database
exports.enviarNotificacao = functions.database.ref('/caminho/da/informacao/{idInformacao}').onUpdate(event => {

    var instanceId = //Use a sua lógica para obter o(s) token(s) do(s) utilizador(es) que deve(m) ser notificado(s)

    const payload = { //Criar a notificação
          notification: {
              title: "Novos Dados!",
              body: "Os dados do fromulário foram atualizados"
          }
    };

    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(instanceId, payload) //enviar a notificação
            .then(function (response) {
              console.log("Mensagem enviada com sucesso:", response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Erro ao enviar a mensagem:", error);
            });

});
```

Comment: Ola Rosario, estava olhando o artigo que creio que atende a minha necessidade, mas ainda tenho algumas duvidas, esse método funciona mesmo com a aplicação fechada ? Preciso enviar uma notificação caso um valor supere o limite pré determinado essa função vai ficar dentro do firebase ou da aplicação? preciso usar o token?

Comment: @RenanSilveira você encontrou a solução, estou em busca disso também. Preciso apenas criar esse broadcast para saber se houve mudanças e ativar a notificação.